# Getting No instance available for a microservice hosted in PCF

Tags: microservices, resttemplate, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry

I have hosted 3 microservices in PCF. One is a eureka server and the other 2 are client and service microservices. The client is supposed to call the service through a rest template call and service will return a string.

I have 1 instance each of the eureka server and the client and 2 instances of the service.

I can see both my client and service registered in the Eureka dashboard. But when i try to access the service from the client[Using a rest template call] I get - 'No instances available for the [service name]'

But if i access my service directly from browser then its works fine and returns the string. But the same URL if called from a rest template returns the exception i mentioned above.

Any suggestions will help

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here are some suggestions for troubleshooting more: 1.) check if you are registering the URL or the container IP in Eureka.  If it's the container IP, check that you have container to container networking installed and access is allowed.  If it's the URL, check that there are no security groups blocking access (they restrict outbound access)   2.) Run `cf ssh`, pick your client app, use `curl` to test sending a request to the service app.  3.) Turn up the log levels to try and get more information.

Comment: @DanielMikusa                                                                                   These are the values i see in public_networks:                          destination: 0.0.0.0-9.255.255.255
protocol: all
destination: 11.0.0.0-169.253.255.255
protocol: all
destination: 169.255.0.0-172.15.255.255
protocol: all
destination: 172.32.0.0-192.167.255.255
protocol: all
destination: 192.169.0.0-255.255.255.255
protocol: all

Comment: How are you accessing the service? Are you giving absolute url of the service? Or are you using url like `https://my-service-name/api/<endpoint>`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the @LoadBalance on restTemplate bean.

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
return new RestTemplate();
}
```

And when calling service you have to use the service name as below.

```
https://SERVICENAME/restpath
```